# How to implement decision variable in AMPL

Tags: math, modeling, ampl

I have an equation and i don't know how to implement it in AMPL for CPLEX.
Here is it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqiA.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What solver are you using with AMPL? Some solvers make this much easier than others.

Comment: i use cplex solver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a linear solver (like CPLEX), the usual approach is to turn this into a linear constraint with a binary variable indicating which of the two cases applies.

```
param eps;
param beta;
param bignum = 1e5;
var z_s_1 binary;
# will have value 0 when z_v <= eps, else 1
var z_s = z_s_1*beta;
var z_v >= 0;

s.t. Define_z_s_1_a: z_s_1 * eps <= z_v;
# so if z_v < eps then z_s_1 must be 0 and hence z_s = 0
s.t. Define_z_s_1_b: z_s_1 * bignum >= z_v - eps;
# so if z_v > eps, then z_s_1 must be > 0 so must be 1, 
# and hence z_s = beta.
```

A couple of considerations:

If you want to be mathematically precise, when `z_v` equals eps exactly, `z_s_1` could take either value, and hence `z_s` could be either 0 or `beta`. But given the limitations of computer arithmetic, we normally don't need to lose sleep about strict vs. non-strict inequalities.

This will prevent solutions with `z_v > bignum+eps`, so `bignum` will need to be large enough to allow reasonable values of `z_v`. However, if you make it too large, you can run into problems with machine arithmetic. For instance, consider the following example:

```
option solver cplex;
param bignum = 1e6;
var x binary;

minimize of: x;

s.t. c1: bignum*x >= 1;
solve;
display x;
```

Evaluating this by hand, since `x` is binary and `bignum*x` >= 1, we can see that `x` must be 1. However, running this through AMPL/CPLEX, I instead get the solution `x=0`, even though this violates `c1`.

The reason for this is that these solvers generally allow a small tolerance for "integer" variables. Hence, it accepts a solution of `x=1e-10` as "close enough" to integer. This satisfies `c1` since `x*bignum >= 1`, but then it rounds `x` to zero. This can be confusing if you're not expecting it! So figure out what the smallest value is for `bignum` that will do the job, based on the largest plausible value for `z_v`, and check results carefully. You may need to tinker with the tolerance parameters.

AMPL does also offer some support for [logical constraints with CPLEX](https://ampl.com/resources/logic-and-constraint-programming-extensions/) but I'm less familiar with those, so I'm not sure if they offer an alternate solution to this problem.