# if condition in ampl

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, glpk

I am new in ampl and I want to use if condition in ampl with the following information:

I have a binary variable     X[p,r], where     {p in P, r in R}.
Now I want to make a new constraint such that the variable R[p,r] is used where X[p,r]=0. 
I do not know how I can write it or even if the ampl can handle it or not, I tried the following constraint but they did not work:

```
s.t. a1{r in R, p in P and X[p,r]=0}: 
s.t. a2{r in R p in P and X[p,r]=0};
s.t. a2{r in R ,p in P, and X[p,r]=0};
s.t. a2{r in R, p in P: and X[p,r]=0};
```

Comment: Do you mean that the constraint is only *present* if `X[p,r] = 0` or that you want a constraint that forces `R[p,r]` to be nonzero if `X[p,r] = 0`?

Comment: I meant  that the constraint is only present if X[p,r] = 0

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 could you please help me with that? if you know ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include a decision variable in the "for all" part of the constraint (in AMPL, the part inside the `{...}`). Instead, you need build into the constraint itself the logic that says the constraint is only active if `X[p,r] = 0`. The way to do that depends on the type of constraint: >=, =, or <=. I'll write each case separately, and I'll do it in a generic way instead of specific to your problem.

In the explanation below, I assume that the constraint is written as

```
a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] >=/=/<= b,
```

where `a[i]` and `b` are constants and `y[i]` are decision variables. I also assume we want the constraint to hold if `x = 0`, where `x` is a binary decision variable, and we don't care whether the constraint holds if `x = 1`.

Let `M` be a new parameter (constant) that equals a large number.

**Greater-than-or-equal-to constraints:**

The constraint is `a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] >= b`. Rewrite it as

```
a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] >= b - Mx.
```

Then, if `x = 0`, the constraint holds, and if `x = 1`, it has no effect since the right-hand side is very negative.

(If all of the `a[i]` are nonnegative, you can instead use

```
a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] >= bx,
```

which is tighter.)

**Less-than-or-equal-to constraints:**

The constraint is `a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] <= b`. Rewrite it as

```
a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] <= b + Mx.
```

Then, if `x = 0`, the constraint holds, and if `x = 1`, it has no effect since the RHS is very large.

**Equality constraints:**

The constraint is `a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] = b`. Rewrite it as

```
a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] <= b + Mx
a[1]y[1] + ... + a[n]y[n] >= b - Mx.
```

Then, if `x = 0`, the equality constraint holds, and if `x = 1`, the constraints have no effect.

*Note*: If your model is relatively large, i.e., it takes a non-negligible amount of time to solve, then you need to be careful with big-`M`-type formulations. In particular, you want `M` to be as small as possible while still enforcing the logic of the constraints above.

Comment: Thank you , I kind of knew these ways but I wanted to use less constraints as much as possible. Do you know if there is a way to count index p such that X[p,r]=0?

Comment: How about `sum {p in P} (1 - X[p,r])`?

Comment: I need to store index p also

Comment: Right. It depends on what you want to do, but one way or another, `r` would have to occur outside this sum. For example, `display {r in R} sum {p in P} (1 - X[p,r])` or `subject to MyConstraint {r in R} sum {p in P} (1 - X[p,r]) >= 5` or whatever.

Comment: Another caveat with big-`M` formulations is that depending on the size of M and the finer details of your solver and numeric tolerances, you can end up with results where e.g. `x=0` and yet `x*M >= 1`. See my [recent answer on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779330/how-to-implement-decision-variable-in-ampl) for an example of this.

Comment: @user9272398: By the way, there is an effort to launch a [Stack Exchange site for Operations Research](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research), where questions like this will be welcome. If you're interested, check it out and consider "committing".

Comment: If you are using CPLEX, Gurobi, or Xpress and your constraint is linear, then you can write

`s.t. a1 {r in R, p in P}: X[p,r] = 0 ==> [your constraint expression]`

which is interpreted as "X[p,r] equals 0 implies [your constraint expression]" or equivalently "if X[p,r] equals 0 then [your constraint expression]". This definition will have the effect that your constraint will only be enforced for p and r such that X[p,r] equals 0 in the solution.

Comment: @4er I am using glpk, how about that?

Comment: With GLPK, you can use one of the linear formulations that @LarrySnyder610 described.