# how I can seperate negative and positive variables?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, ampl, glpk

Let I have a variable UT[i,j,k,r], whose define as a sum of 2 other variables.

```
UT[i,j,k,r]= U[i,j,k,r]+D[i,j,k,r]
```

Now I want to write some constraints just for positive UT[i,j,k,r]! what I can do?

I tried many ways: I defined a binary variable whose is 1 if UT is positive and 0 otherwise but it didn't solve my problem because multiplying them is complicated. is there any way to store the indices where UT is positive?

Comment: There is some discussion about how to activate/deactivate constraints based on another decision variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56025131/3453768); 4er's comment about how to do this easily in AMPL might especially help.

Comment: I answered this question on the AMPL user forum, so I'll post it here in a form adapted for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `BT[i,j,k,r]` is your binary variable. Then if you are using CPLEX, Gurobi, or Xpress as your solver, you can write an "indicator constraint" like this:

> `BT[i,j,k,r] = 1 ==> *your constraint*`

This is the easiest way. Alternatively, for any solver, if your constraint is linear then it is possible to transform the indicator constraint to an equivalent linear constraint, without multiplying the binary variable by any other variables. (If your constraint is nonlinear then there may be a transformation as well.) To learn about how such transformations are done, see the answer by @LarrySnyder610 to [if condition in ampl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56025131/3453768).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split UT into two parts: UTplus and UTminus, both of which are >= 0. Then define UT = UTplus - UTminus.

Now you need to add a constraint that says that at most one of the two can be non-zero. There are several options for this:

1. You can use an indicator constraint like you suggested and as 4er explained. Use a binary helper variable to indicate that if that variable is 1 then UTminus must be zero and if the helper variable is 0 then UTplus must be zero. If you can derive an upper bound M for UTplus and UTminus then you can also just add a constraint `UTplus <= M*binary` and `UTminus <= M*(1 - binary)`. If M is not too big this may give better performance.
2. You can use an SOS constraint that contains UTplus and UTminus (you need one SOS for each index in the variable). That also enforces that at most one of the two can be non-zero but does not introduce any new variables. Whether this is more efficient than indicator or big-M has to be tested.
3. If both, UTplus and UTminus have a positive coefficient in the objective function (for minimization) then there are chances that in any optimal solution one of the two will be zero **automatically**. This depends on what exactly the variable UT represents in your model. Take a look at your model and see whether you can prove that property. Then you don't need any extra constraints or variables at all.