# python realize production planning and scheduling issue

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to use pulp package to do production scheduling. I have orders with different models. Different factories make different models with different speed. 
I am supposed to plan all the orders but my objective is just to make only next few (i.e. 6 days) days to finish more products. 
The constraints are mainly that the leadtime(due date) and the time the order can start to produce(release date).

I am not sure if I use the pulp in the right way:
I set LpVariables r as release date. and c as complete days. Like order i will begin in  facory j at the time r and complete after a period c.

```
r=LpVariable('release date',(o,f),0)
c=LpVariable('complete days',(o,f),0)
d=LpVariable('due date',(o,f),0)
```

I assume that the  objective fuction should be like :

```
prob=lpProblem('aps',LpMaximize)
prob+=LpSum([c[o][f]*speed[o][f] for o in orders for f in factories if d[o][f]<=6])+lpSum([(6-r[o][f])*speed[o][f] for o in orders for f in factories if d[o][f]>=6 and r[o][f]<=6])
```

My question is how to make it right. Maybe use the different package? Or Just change some codes?

Comment: Post the objective function including the constraints as well

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56025131/3453768) help you? That answer was written for AMPL but the logic is the same if you are working with `PuLP`.

Comment: Is `A` a linear or an integer variable? Would be helpful to understand a little more of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LpVariable.dicts` rather than `LpVariable`. The latter creates a single instance of an LpVariable object. The former creates a dictionary where the keys are based on the indexs (second) parameter and the values are LpVariable objects, which is what you want.

I think `LpVariable` should probably throw an error when you pass (o,f) as what seems to be an extraneous parameter.

You can see the difference between the two by printing out r, c, and d using `LpVariable` and `LpVariable.dicts`.

```
o = [1, 2, 3]
f = ['a', 'b', 'c']

r = LpVariable('release date',(o,f),0)
c = LpVariable('complete days',(o,f),0)
d = LpVariable('due date',(o,f),0)

>>>print(r, c, d)
release_date complete_days due_date

# this error occurs because c is an object, not a dictionary where the values are objects.
>>>prob += lpSum([c[o][f]*speed[o][f] for o in orders ...])
TypeError: 'LpVariable' object is not subscriptable 

# correct approach
r = LpVariable.dicts('release date',(o,f),0)
c = LpVariable.dicts('complete days',(o,f),0)
d = LpVariable.dicts('due date',(o,f),0)

>>>print(r, c, d)
{1: {'a': release_date_1_a, 'b': release_date_1_b, 'c': release_date_1_c},
  2: {'a': release_date_2_a, 'b': release_date_2_b, 'c': release_date_2_c},
  3: {'a': release_date_3_a, 'b': release_date_3_b, 'c': release_date_3_c}},
 {1: {'a': complete_days_1_a, 'b': complete_days_1_b, 'c': complete_days_1_c},
  2: {'a': complete_days_2_a, 'b': complete_days_2_b, 'c': complete_days_2_c},
  3: {'a': complete_days_3_a, 'b': complete_days_3_b, 'c': complete_days_3_c}},
 {1: {'a': due_date_1_a, 'b': due_date_1_b, 'c': due_date_1_c},
  2: {'a': due_date_2_a, 'b': due_date_2_b, 'c': due_date_2_c},
  3: {'a': due_date_3_a, 'b': due_date_3_b, 'c': due_date_3_c}}]

>>>print(r[1]['b'])
release_date_1_b
```

Note also that you have some capitalization errors. Your code should read LpProblem, not lpProblem, and lpSum instead of LpSum.